# asp.net: load aspx file server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument, server.mappath

I have some aspx pages that dynamically generate xml (from backcode).
I want to load that xml to a XmlDocument on another page (server side).

But using XmlDocument.load(MapPath(path)) only loads text from file, backcode is not interpreted. Is there any way to load aspx page on the server as it would be viewed from the client?

Edit: problem is that when loaded by XmlDocument.load(MapPath(path)) backcode is not interpreted. I resolved this by just coping code that created the xml - but maybe there is some way to get aspx page on server the way it is viewed in client?

Comment: XmlDocument.load reads content of xml document which you are getting what else  you require to show; the code that generate xml file.

Comment: Run your xml generation code and use `XmlDocument.LoadXml` method if you want to create xml document from string

Comment: Orifjon: yes, It is probably the only way.